# Merge Array in a loop

Tags: php, arrays

I am merging a three dimensional array into a two dimensional array by using array_merge.

I get the result I need when I have five keys that I am merging into one array.

```
$result = array_merge($records[0], $records[1], $records[2], $records[3], $records[4]);
```

However, I may have 2 keys, or 10.  I can't have static code like this.

I can of course use the below code to get how many keys there are:

```
$count = count($records);
```

But how do I then use that to build an array merge so that it contains all of the appropriate keys?  ie:  If there are four, great it will produce the same code as above, but if there are 3 then it will onl do 0, 1, 2.

if there are 3 keys:

```
$result = array_merge($records[0], $records[1], $records[2]);
```

If there are 8 keys:

```
$result = array_merge($records[0], $records[1], $records[2], $records[3], $records[4], $records[5], $records[6], $records[7]);
```

Thanks in advance for this silly question.  I know it is simple!!

Comment: What is the value of `$records`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = [];
foreach ($records as $record) {
    $result = array_merge($result, $record);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Convert a multi-dimensional array into a single-dimensional array.
 * @author Sean Cannon, LitmusBox.com | seanc@litmusbox.com
 * @param  array $array The multi-dimensional array.
 * @return array
 */
function array_flatten($array) { 
  if (!is_array($array)) { 
    return false; 
  } 
  $result = array(); 
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
    if (is_array($value)) { 
      $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value)); 
    } else { 
      $result[$key] = $value; 
    } 
  } 
  return $result; 
}
```

This function should help you. It converts a multi-dimensional array into a single-dimensional array.

---

> Source: https://gist.github.com/SeanCannon/6585889